# Move subdirectories to parent based on name

Tags: python

I am trying to look into the subdirectories and move them to a different one based on their name. This is all from Google Drive takeout. There are about 40 takeout folders with the following syntax:

E:\gdrive\takeout\takeout-XYZ-001\Takeout\Drive

I want to move the folder 'Drive' (or photos, etc.) from each of the subdirectories in 'takeout' and move to:

E:\storage\ [Drive / Photos]

I tried the following code:

```
import os, shutil
from pathlib import Path

for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('E:\gdrive\takeout'):
        if subfolders == 'Drive':
            shutil.copy(os.path(subfolders, 'E:\storage\Drive')) 
        else:
            continue
```

Now I sense I'm not using some (maybe any) of this correctly to check whether Drive exists and then move it, but I'm a bit stuck while trying to understand this. I also want to make sure I don't overwrite what I've just moved into the folder.

I've tried to read a few similar examples, but keep getting stuck and flipping between looking at various methods but can't make any work.

Answer (score 1):

`subfolders` is a *list* of strings so it cannot be literally the string `'Drive'`.

```
for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(r'E:\gdrive\takeout'):
    for dirname in subfolders:
        if dirname == 'Drive':
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(foldername, dirname), r'E:\storage\Drive')
```

The `else:` is optional; if you don't have anything you want to put there, just leave it out.

Notice also the use of `r'...'` strings around Windows paths, and the fix to the arguments for `shutil.copy` (I had to guess a bit what you hoped to do there).

Using `os.walk` is somewhat iffy here; if you have multiple directories with the same name, should the later ones replace the ones you copied earlier, or end up nested inside them, or something else? If you don't expect multiple matches, perhaps you already know the paths and don't need to recurse? But in the scenario where you know the name but not exactly the path, perhaps this code can be useful.

Comment: Thank you! There are several 'takeout-001', 'takeout-040' directories then the same sub directory, 'Drive'. Ideally the code would take the folders inside 'Drive' and put them in one single drive folder.

Comment: That still doesn't explain how to cope if there are entries with the same name. The current code will just plonk the second one inside the first one, I believe, but after that you'll get an error if it finds still more.

Comment: These problems have been hashed out many times in the past, so you can probably find an existing question with answers you could try if you need more help with that. This solves the actual problem you tried to resolve, as far as I can see; perhaps you can [mark it as accepted?](/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Also please note the update just now; there was another error which I hadn't noticed before.

Comment: Thanks! To answer, I’d like to put the folders and files from each Drive folder into just a single Drive folder. Does that make sense? Also I tried many others as you suggest, just was struggling to make it work as most seem to point to changing the final folder, not when the directory change is higher up the chain as it were.

Comment: What you want and what is technically feasible may be two different things. Again, the crucial question is how to handle duplicates when copying files from many different places which may contain files with the same name; and again, this is pretty far outside the scope of your original question. Please (accept this answer, or post one of your own and accept that if you prefer, and) post a new question with enough details.

Comment: No this is entirely what the original question asks. And I imagine it is feasible - hence I asked the question. I don’t understand why you’re pushing me to “accept” your answer frankly. I came to ask for ideas on how to solve it.

Comment: We can solve a question with clear requirements. You continue to refuse to clarify them. This answer answers the question you _actually_ asked.

Comment: "I also don't want to make sure I don't overwrite what I have just moved in there" in the original question. I have clarified all the questions you have asked. I don't understand what other question you have asked that I haven't answered?

Comment: Am I right in understanding the appropriate thing to do is to re-post the question with more specifics?

Comment: Yes, exactly; please describe exactly the required behavior for the corner case and your best effort at solving it yourself, without syntax errors in your code etc.

Comment: Ok great,  thank you. I'll try to outline it as best I can further